# How do I filter certain column using Laravel Scout

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout, meilisearch

#### `Products` table

| id | name | commercial_name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pro1 | Pro Com1 | 1 |
| 2 | Pro2 | Pro Com2 | 2 |

#### `Categories` table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat 1 |
| 2 | Cat 2 |

#### What I am trying to do

I am using Meilisearch with Laravel Scout and I am trying to make the user `search` and `filter`.

For example JSON get request from frontend:

```json
{
    "query": "Com2",
    "filters": [
        {
            "category_name": "cat 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This should return the product with `id 2` and its assigned category.

In other words:
User may search in multiple tables with relationships and filter by each table column.

Kindly know that filter should not be the exact match of the value

#### What I have tried

```php
// THIS WORKS FOR NORMAL SEARCH
$query = Product::search($request->query)->paginate(30);

// THIS DOES NOT WORK
$query = Product::search($request->query)
    ->whereHas(
        'category',
        function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->filters[0]['category_name'].'%');
        }
    )
    ->paginate(30);
```

Here I am trying to add where condition to the search query

Comment: you can try the whereHas method to filter the results based on the related model's data.

Comment: The `Product::search()` method returns a Scout search engine, not an eloquent search builder. You cannot add eloquent or database query builder conditons like this (the `whereHas()`. You can send a query string into `Product::search()` and you can pass in some additional options which include simple filters through a callback to `Product::search()`. The callback syntax will vary with each search engine, so Mielisearch has its own way to drive it.

Comment: @Jaad were you able to solve this?